# Why does my program end after I input a certain amount of letters to the array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Every time I insert a certain amount of letters to the array, my console closes instantly. Is there something wrong with my code? Also, is there a different way of counting the amount of vocals?

```
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int i=0;
    int leng=1;
    int voc = 0;
    char seq[leng] = {};
    cout << "lets create the sequence..." << endl << "enter '*' to end sequence" << endl;

    for (i; i < leng; i++) {

        leng++;
        cin >> seq[i];
        if (seq[i] == '*') {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "lets check the frequency of the 5 vocals..." << endl;

    for (int z=0; z < leng; z++) {

        if (seq[z] == 'a' || seq[z] == 'e' || seq[z] == 'i' || seq[z] == 'o' || seq[z] == 'u') {
            voc+=1;
        }
    }

    leng-=2;

    cout << "so out of... " << leng << " letters, " << voc << " of them are vocals.";
}
```

Comment: You're making a VLA which is not valid in C++. It also has length `1` which is UB when you try to put strings into it.

Comment: VLA = variable length array. UB = undefined behaviour.

Comment: You can't extend an array after its creation.

Comment: When do you think `i < leng` is going to become false if you increment both `i` and `leng` in the loop?

Comment: You have `string` at your disposal. Use it, it will make your life *much* easier.

Comment: Just point out that `vocal`, in this context should be translated to `vowel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying Tianxu's answer, here's my solution using algorithms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int count = 0;
   string letters;
   cout << "Please enter the letters" << endl;
   cin >> letters;

   cout << "lets check the frequency of the 5 vocals..." << endl;
   count_if(letters.begin(), letters.end(), [](char letter){
        return letter == 'a' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'u';
        });
   cout << "so out of... " << letters.size() << " letters, " << count << " of them are vocals.";
}
```

The assembly created by godbolt is a lot smaller this way, which may hint at faster execution, but doesn't actually prove it without benchmarks.
https://godbolt.org/z/ay3aJT (algorithm) vs https://godbolt.org/z/gFNkr1 (hand spun)

**Edit**: in case lambdas (the `[]( ... ){ ... }` thing that's the last parameter of the `count` algorithm) are still a bit advanced for you, there's also a version using a regular function, though it's less idiomatic (advanced aside: the same assembly is created as in the lambda case, but only if I supply the `inline` keyword to the function definition):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//if I inline this, the same code as in the lambda case is generated on godbolt
 bool is_vacol(char letter)
 {
     return (letter == 'a' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'u');
 };

int main()
{
   int count = 0;
   string letters;
   cout << "Please enter the letters" << endl;
   cin >> letters;

    cout << "lets check the frequency of the 5 vocals..." << endl;
    count_if(letters.begin(), letters.end(), is_vacol);
    cout << "so out of... " << letters.size() << " letters, " << count << " of them are vocals.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think your code can't be compiled**, reasons as follows:

1. not I/O header file included
2. you cannot use variables as array length
3. no `return`
4. etc.

I rewrite your program in your way:

```cpp
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 bool is_vacol(char letter)
 {
     if(letter == 'a' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'u')
         return true;
     else
         return false;
 }

 int main()
 {
     int count = 0;
     string letters;
     cout << "Please enter the letters" << endl;
     cin >> letters;
     int len = letters.size();

     cout << "lets check the frequency of the 5 vocals..." << endl;
     for(int i = 0;i < len; i++)
     {
         if(is_vacol(letters[i]))
             count++;
     }
     cout << "so out of... " << len << " letters, " << count << " of them are vocals.";
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `main` is the only function in C++ (and C?) that allows you to leave out the return value even though it's not void. Basically, there's an invisible `return 0` at the end of `int main(){}`

Comment: About `is_vacol`, just `return letter == 'a' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'u'`. When you write `if(x) return true; else return false;` it's usually a code smell

Comment: I wander if will it be faster? @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: @Tianxu even if it was, we're talking rather small inputs and the `if` will probably be optimized away by the compiler anyway, so nothing to be really concerned about, performance-wise.

Comment: I agree with your opinion : ) @FedericoklezCulloca

Answer (score 0):

Do not give an array in C++ a certain size then play with it and change it, if you do not want to give it a size leave it empty
    Char list[];
Or a better way is to use string, it was done to make your life way easier, no length etc and can then be accessed as a char array